# Column gets duplicated once the Query is refreshed

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

Here is the M code of the query:

```
    Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("Mappings.xlsx"), null, true),
    dpt_cc_uniquekey_Table = Source{[Item="Dpt_cc_q_map",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Filtered year and Q" = Table.SelectRows(dpt_cc_uniquekey_Table, each ([Quarter] = "Q3") and ([Year] = 2023)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered year and Q",{"Quarter", "Year", "cc_unique_key"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each ([#"Department/Entity"] = "HR Finance")),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows", {"Cost center to be charged"}),
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="HR_Finance_cc"]}[Content],
    DataWithPercentage = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"Department/Entity", type text}, {"Cost center to be charged", Int64.Type}, {"Percentage", Int64.Type}})
in
    DataWithPercentage
```

Every time the Query is refreshed, the column "Percentage" gets duplicated.

Where is the mistake in the code?

Thank you

Comment: Your code literally does nothing except read in the range HR_Finance_cc and then return it unchanged.  The first six rows of code are not even used. Any duplication is happening somewhere else